Well-posedness for linear transport equations with fractional diffusion term
I have a rather applied problem where I consider an equation of the form
$$ \partial_{t} u + V\cdot \nabla u = -(-\Delta)^s u, \quad (t,x) \in (0,\infty)\times \mathbf{R}^d, \quad u(0,x) = u_0. {}$$
Here $u = u(t,x)$ is a scalar function, $(-\Delta)^s$ is the fractional Laplacian with $s \in [1/2,1)$ and $V$ is a smooth vector field.
My question regards well-posedness results for this kind of equation or results that can be applied to obtain (if possible) such results. My initial idea was to look at unbounded perturbation of the transport semigroup, but that did not lead anywhere. Although there is an increasing amount of literature on fractional PDE, I could not find anything relevant there either.
Therefore, any suggestions for papers or books tackling this (or similar) problem or possible techniques to apply are much welcomed!

I assume you want a minus sign on the right-hand side. Instead of looking at unbounded perturbations of the transport semigroup, look at unbounded perturbations of the fractional diffusion semigroup.  Any text on analytic semigroups will get you started on that. Energy estimates are another possible approach, which would also work is $s<1/2$.
